# How to make nginx web-server show various content depends on how much times you reached the page

Tags: nginx, proxy, webserver

In example we have page1.html and page2.html
When user reaches out site.com/page - he see's page1.html, but if he will reach page second time he'll see page2.html

Comment: Any state management like this usually achieved using cookies on the application side; this isn't the nginx job.

Answer (score 0):

Did it on myself, you just need to create an [upstream_module](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html)  with 2 servers and [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) to it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).